# DirectoryEntry IIS access permission

Tags: c#, windows, security, iis, iis-8

I have one console application which list website binding in IIS

```
using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc/" + GetWebSiteId())) {
    var bindings = directoryEntry.Properties["ServerBindings"]; 
}
```

I call this console application from ASP.NET via process

```
var process = new Process {
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
       FileName = "c:/app.exe",
       Arguments = "check",
       UseShellExecute = false,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
       CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

Everything works fine on development machine under Widows 7 / IIS 7.5, but when i test on Windows 2012 / IIS 8 im getting "Access is denied" error.

Error log

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied.
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.ChildEnumerator..ctor(DirectoryEntry container)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.GetEnumerator()
at IISSubdomainManagement.Program.GetWebSiteId()
at IISSubdomainManagement.Program.TotalBindings()
at IISSubdomainManagement.Program.Main(String[] args)"
```

p.s Application pool identity is "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

---

I forget to mention, my console app works fine on my server when I run it from CMD

Comment: I've had this one before and if I recall, the issue is either where it is looking for the AD server or the credentials don't have the correct permissions.  It's annoying because it works fine locally

Answer (score 2):

You need to give permission to the IUSR account to access and execute `C:\app.exe`. [This link](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis) should provide you with the necessary information to find the right account.

Comment: IUSR and IIS_IUSRS have full security control on app.exe, but still dont work

Comment: I can confirm the COMException you get when the IIS_IUSRS don't have access is `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.` (rather than `Access denied`)

Answer (score 2):

In IIS 7/8 go **Control Panel** / Program And Features / Turn Windows features on or off, and **check all items** from: Web Managment Tools, (it's include: IIS Managment Service, II 6 Managment Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

You have probably granted the permission to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' rather than to the virtual account that actually corresponds to that Application Pool. Read through the [Microsoft's description](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) or search online for virtual identity IIS, etc.

On your development machine, you probably have some sort of Full Admin rights, so it is not as restricted.

If you still have problems after that, I would recommend replicating the error with a [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) running, so you can see exactly what process is accessing which resource with which identity. However, I would recommend replicating the issue on your development machine rather than running Process Monitor on the production. It takes a little bit of learning to be able to run it efficiently.

Comment: done, i added my virtual identity created by my application pool as full security rights on app.exe but still that error...

Comment: When i select "LocalSystem" as application pool identity, everything works, but why i cant as ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: LocalSystem is a real identity, the one one is a special case. I updated the main comment with additional suggestions on next step of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution worked for me ==>

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-adsi-error-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80005000-unknown-error-0x80005000.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage